# Property Data Type issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, types

Why the Intellisense displays a "**?**" character after the datatype? (***Long?***), what will mean? ...is not sure that the property value will return a Long type? if yes then why not?

Is the first time that I've seen this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means the type is nullable.

Usually value types aren't nullable.  A few versions ago .NET introduced a struct to help with that, called `Nullable(Of T)`.  Putting a `?` after the value type is shorthand for that.

So `Long?` is the same as `Nullable(Of Long)`.